# Не сохраняет товары в Open cart

Tags: php, opencart

Добрый день, интересует такой вопрос, почему не сохраняет удаленные/добавленные товары в Open Cart в админ панели. Если вкратце, то я создавал новый модуль по типу модуля "Рекомендуемые". С автокомплитом. Поиск товаров по имени работает нормально, товары добавляются, но если нажать кнопку "Сохранить", то неважно сколько я добавил/удалил товаров - список снова остается прежним, т.е. снова показывает полный список существующих в базе товаров. Сделаю несколько скриншотов для ясности. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверьте SQL-запрос на сохранение в модели и посмотрите в админке логи

Comment: Какая версия opencart? Как ты пробовал решать данную проблему?